# Segmentation violation detected on run

Tags: matlab

I'm new to MATLAB and I get the following crash information when running GISTIC2 based on MCR. No problem running that algorithm in other machine we are using.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
       Segmentation violation detected at Thu Jul  8 23:01:05 2021
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Configuration:
  Crash Decoding     : Disabled
  Current Visual     : 0x21 (class 4, depth 24)
  Default Encoding   : UTF-8
  GNU C Library      : 2.31 stable
  MATLAB Architecture: glnxa64
  MATLAB Root        : /home/lcj/Biosoft/GISTIC2/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83
  MATLAB Version     : 8.3.0.532 (R2014a)
  Operating System   : Linux 5.8.0-59-generic #66~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 17 11:14:10 UTC 2021 x86_64
  Processor ID       : x86 Family 143 Model 96 Stepping 1, AuthenticAMD
  Virtual Machine    : Java 1.7.0_11-b21 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
  Window System      : The X.Org Foundation (12009000), display :0
Fault Count: 1
Abnormal termination:
Segmentation violation
Register State (from fault):
  RAX = 0000000000000000  RBX = 00007f7790b2c190
  RCX = 0000000000000000  RDX = 0000000000000000
  RSP = 00007f77f2becde8  RBP = 00007f77ec0376c0
  RSI = 000000003e07c725  RDI = 0000000000000000
   R8 = 0000000000000007   R9 = 00312d3634363031
  R10 = 00007f77f2becc70  R11 = 0000000000000000
  R12 = 0000000000000000  R13 = 00007f77f2bed180
  R14 = 0000000000000000  R15 = 0000000000000000
  RIP = 00007f7807063675  EFL = 0000000000010283
   CS = 0033   FS = 0000   GS = 0000
Stack Trace (from fault):
[  0] 0x00007f7807063675                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+01619573
[  1] 0x00007f77f588ec18                  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6+00134168 XLoadQueryFont+00000056
[  2] 0x00007f77f870adf0 /home/lcj/Biosoft/GISTIC2/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83/bin/glnxa64/libmwuix.so+00261616
[  3] 0x00007f77f870baae /home/lcj/Biosoft/GISTIC2/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83/bin/glnxa64/libmwuix.so+00264878
[  4] 0x00007f77f870bd29 /home/lcj/Biosoft/GISTIC2/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83/bin/glnxa64/libmwuix.so+00265513
[  5] 0x00007f77f8e5d143 /home/lcj/Biosoft/GISTIC2/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83/bin/glnxa64/libmwgui.so+00663875 _Z21wm_SetUnadjWindowFontP10WinRec_tagP6mxFont+00000083
[  6] 0x00007f77f8e5d74b /home/lcj/Biosoft/GISTIC2/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83/bin/glnxa64/libmwgui.so+00665419 _Z22wm_GetDeviceFontExtentP10WinRec_tagP6mxFontPKcdP6mwrect+00000315
[  7] 0x00007f77f8e78fff /home/lcj/Biosoft/GISTIC2/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83/bin/glnxa64/libmwgui.so+00778239 uiGetDeviceFont+00000815
[  8] 0x00007f77f8e79171 /home/lcj/Biosoft/GISTIC2/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83/bin/glnxa64/libmwgui.so+00778609 _Z15uiSetWindowFontP10WinRec_tagP6mxFont+00000017
[  9] 0x00007f77f8e5d013 /home/lcj/Biosoft/GISTIC2/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83/bin/glnxa64/libmwgui.so+00663571 _Z16wm_SetWindowFontP10WinRec_tagP6mxFont+00000083
[ 10] 0x00007f77a5d81195 /home/lcj/Biosoft/GISTIC2/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83/bin/glnxa64/libmwhg.so+05001621
[ 11] 0x00007f77f8e9489d /home/lcj/Biosoft/GISTIC2/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83/bin/glnxa64/libmwgui.so+00891037 _ZN11gui_objects10tickpicker12nicefyLimitsERNS0_14AxisDescriptorENS0_8AxisTypeE+00000173
[ 12] 0x00007f77f8e94cc3 /home/lcj/Biosoft/GISTIC2/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83/bin/glnxa64/libmwgui.so+00892099 _ZN11gui_objects10tickpicker12nicefyLimitsERNS0_14AxisDescriptorE+00000019
[ 13] 0x00007f77a5d816d9 /home/lcj/Biosoft/GISTIC2/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83/bin/glnxa64/libmwhg.so+05002969
[ 14] 0x00007f77a5ce57df /home/lcj/Biosoft/GISTIC2/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83/bin/glnxa64/libmwhg.so+04364255
[ 15] 0x00007f77a5cd0b1f /home/lcj/Biosoft/GISTIC2/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83/bin/glnxa64/libmwhg.so+04279071
[ 16] 0x00007f77a5dd4740 /home/lcj/Biosoft/GISTIC2/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83/bin/glnxa64/libmwhg.so+05343040
[ 17] 0x00007f77a5dd427c /home/lcj/Biosoft/GISTIC2/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83/bin/glnxa64/libmwhg.so+05341820
[ 18] 0x00007f77a5dc72b0 /home/lcj/Biosoft/GISTIC2/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83/bin/glnxa64/libmwhg.so+05288624
[ 19] 0x00007f77f746bded /home/lcj/Biosoft/GISTIC2/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83/bin/glnxa64/libmwudd.so+00634349
[ 20] 0x00007f77f7465153 /home/lcj/Biosoft/GISTIC2/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83/bin/glnxa64/libmwudd.so+00606547 _ZN11UDInterface15notifyPropEventEP16UDDatabaseClientPK10UDPropInfoPK11UDEventInfoP7UDEvent+00000115
[ 21] 0x00007f77f7468671 /home/lcj/Biosoft/GISTIC2/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83/bin/glnxa64/libmwudd.so+00620145 _ZN11UDInterface4setEEP16UDDatabaseClientP10UDPropInfoPvP13UDErrorStatus+00000593
[ 22] 0x00007f77a5dd15b6 /home/lcj/Biosoft/GISTIC2/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83/bin/glnxa64/libmwhg.so+05330358
[ 23] 0x00007f77a5dcbadd /home/lcj/Biosoft/GISTIC2/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83/bin/glnxa64/libmwhg.so+05307101
[ 24] 0x00007f77a5dca0d0 /home/lcj/Biosoft/GISTIC2/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83/bin/glnxa64/libmwhg.so+05300432
[ 25] 0x00007f77a5db06f5 /home/lcj/Biosoft/GISTIC2/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83/bin/glnxa64/libmwhg.so+05195509
[ 26] 0x00007f77a5dbdfd0 /home/lcj/Biosoft/GISTIC2/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83/bin/glnxa64/libmwhg.so+05251024
[ 27] 0x00007f77a5db7408 /home/lcj/Biosoft/GISTIC2/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83/bin/glnxa64/libmwhg.so+05223432
[ 28] 0x00007f77a5dbe432 /home/lcj/Biosoft/GISTIC2/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83/bin/glnxa64/libmwhg.so+05252146
[ 29] 0x00007f77a5dc3113 /home/lcj/Biosoft/GISTIC2/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83/bin/glnxa64/libmwhg.so+05271827 hgSet+00001107
[ 30] 0x00007f77a6c80742 /home/lcj/Biosoft/GISTIC2/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83/bin/glnxa64/libmwhgbuiltins.so+00345922
...
[125] 0x00007f77fba703bf /home/lcj/Biosoft/GISTIC2/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00365503
[126] 0x00007f77fba6b28f /home/lcj/Biosoft/GISTIC2/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00344719
[127] 0x00007f78070d3609              /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0+00038409
If this problem is reproducible, please submit a Service Request via:
    http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/
A technical support engineer might contact you with further information.
Thank you for your help.** This crash report has been saved to disk as /home/lcj/matlab_crash_dump.29508-1 **
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

After renaming the libstdc++.so.6 library to libstdc++.so.6.old in ~/Biosoft/GISTIC2/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83/sys/os/glnxa64, I got the following crash information.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
       Segmentation violation detected at Sat Jul 10 23:22:39 2021
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration:
  Crash Decoding     : Disabled
  Current Visual     : 0x21 (class 4, depth 24)
  Default Encoding   : UTF-8
  GNU C Library      : 2.31 stable
  MATLAB Architecture: glnxa64
  MATLAB Root        : /home/lcj/Biosoft/GISTIC2/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83
  MATLAB Version     : 8.3.0.532 (R2014a)
  Operating System   : Linux 5.8.0-59-generic #66~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 17 11:14:10 UTC 2021 x86_64
  Processor ID       : x86 Family 143 Model 96 Stepping 1, AuthenticAMD
  Virtual Machine    : Java 1.7.0_11-b21 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
  Window System      : The X.Org Foundation (12009000), display :0

Fault Count: 1


Abnormal termination:
Segmentation violation

Register State (from fault):
  RAX = 0000000000000000  RBX = 00007f26c0b99880
  RCX = 0000000000000000  RDX = 0000000000000000
  RSP = 00007f2720dcede8  RBP = 00007f271c0376c0
  RSI = 000000003e07c725  RDI = 0000000000000000

   R8 = 0000000000000007   R9 = 00312d3634363031
  R10 = 00007f2720dcec70  R11 = 0000000000000000
  R12 = 0000000000000000  R13 = 00007f2720dcf180
  R14 = 0000000000000000  R15 = 0000000000000000

  RIP = 00007f2735246675  EFL = 0000000000010283

   CS = 0033   FS = 0000   GS = 0000

Stack Trace (from fault):


Caught "std::exception" Exception message is:
FatalException

Error:FatalException
```

Any clues to solve this errors?

Comment: At the bottom of the stack trace it says “If this problem is reproducible, please submit a Service Request via:
    http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/“. Have you done this? MATLAB is a commercial product, use their customer support.

Comment: did you solve the prob? I got same problem and do not know the solution